# Recieved an SMS that deleted all my SMS

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, cyanogenmod, sms, samsung-galaxy-ace, go-sms

A weird thing happened to me today. I received an SMS and upon opening it from the notification bar on top, my SMS are all gone. I didn't even get to read the message. I have my SMS backed-up from a week ago so it's not much of an issue. But then how can this possibly happen? I am using GoSMS and CyanogenMod 7.2 btw. Any thoughts on what could've caused this?

**Update**
Okay now 5 days later, all my contacts have disappeared on it's own. I wasn't doing anything at all. I just notice my contacts are all gone. I did re-sync from Google and they're all back but what could possibly cause that?

Comment: maybe if you had a copy of the SMS and it's properties that would help a bit

Comment: @ThaSaleni unfortunately when clicked the SMS it pointed me to an empty inbox so there's no record of it at all.